# Return empty value for varchar column from java jdbc in kuwait country

Tags: oracle, jdbc, varchar

I am getting empty values for varchar column in kuwait country. I am using jdbc connection to hit oracle database(Kuwait-Oracle Database). The same program is working in india(Indian - Oracle Database).

Is there any regional based declaration in jdk or oracle database?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/advanc.htm

Comment: It could be that your query returns different results based on which timezone it's being issued from - or baed on the timezone of the database. Can you share more details (query, column type, etc.)?

Comment: I fixed this issue. This is character set conversion issue. Client database using different character set. Thanks.